# MVC 4.0 with Entity Framework 5 - if you're working with only a view, do you need to add the child objects to the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I'm doing a little project where it's my first time using MVC 4.0 with Entity Framework 5 + Web API.

I brought in to my model only 1 view (vw0) and I want to query this view to display it on my web page.

This view is a UNION of 2 other views.

```
SELECT * FROM vw1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Vw2
```

vw0 brings back over a million records. In order for me to just test this, I tried to do this:

```
// GET: /Data/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Data_vw_0.ToList().Take(5));
        }
```

However, every time I try to go to:

```
*/Data/
```

I get the following error:

> OutOfMemoryException was unhandled by user code
>
> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I'm new to this whole thing so I needed a hand.

I'm just trying to display the data on the web page.

I was able to display data normally if I used a database table but for some reason with this view, it isn't working.

The view DOES work if I go straight into SQL and try to run it.

My question is, do I need to add both the views that are PART of the mother view (vw0) AS WELL AS the tables they relate to OR do I just have to add the ONE view to my model (vw0)?

Comment: Perhaps this exception you get because EF can't return back all data from db, these data so large.

Comment: How would I get passed that? I tried to do ToList().Take(5) and it still gives me that error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was no, I don't need to add the tables related to the view. I decided to use the actual tables and query them instead of using the Views -- they were giving me too many issues.